# What is the purpose of the environmental variable PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7

On windows 7, I currently don't have a python path. Can I safely make one? If so, how do I do it?

Upon making this variable, I can no longer load Spyder (IDE) without it crashing. Does anyone know why?

I would like to edit my existing python path if possible, but just don't know why it isn't already there in environmental variables.

I would ultimately like to be able to run "python myscript.py" and have myscript be in a different directory from the call directory.

Answer (score 1):

`PYTHONPATH` adds new paths to the ones Python uses by default. The path in total determines where Python will look for modules when you import them.

Look at [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) to see the combination of the defaults with your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. It's likely that Spyder is loading a module that exists in two different places and the wrong one comes first.

Answer (score 0):

When you import modules in python, python searches for the module in the directories in `PYTHONPATH`, in addition to some other directories.

In order to be able to run your script as `> myscript.py`, you want to put your script somewhere on `PATH` ([here are some instructions for viewing or updating `PATH`](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/set-path-system-variable-windows-7-8/)), this is where the OS looks for scripts and programs when you give it a command. I believe that in windows the `.py` extension must be associated with python for windows to know that `myscript.py` should be run using python. This should happen automatically when python in installed, but maybe someone with more windows knowledge can comment on this.

Comment: To run the `myscript.py` from the command line like that, the directory it resides in must have been added to Window's `PATH` environment variable. You can do this permanently in one of the tabs of the the `System` control panel or manually each time you start the command shell.

Answer (score 0):

it has role similar to path.  this variable tells the python interpreter where to 
locate the module files imported into a program.  it should include the python source library directory and the directories contain in python source code